# Calculate average number from 3 numbers inside of an object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function

I have an assignment at school that asks us to create a function to calculate the average mark of 3 students using an existing object in an array. I have the array and function below with the objects pushing to the empty array (also part of the assignment).

I've been spending the last hour reading and trying different ways to write the function and I cant seem to put it together to add the current marks and divide them by the array length.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing and where I'm going wrong?

```
let classList = [];

const enrollStudent = (firstName, lastName, age, currentMark) => {
      newStudent = {firstName, lastName, age, currentMark};
      classList.push(newStudent);
      console.log(classList);
  };

  addNewStudent("Mark", "Smith", 24, 85);
  addNewStudent("Dane", "Joe", 21, 90);
  addNewStudent("Steven", "McKnight", 23, 54);

const getClassAverage = arr => classList.reduce((newStudent.currentMark) => currentMark + currentMark, 0) / classList.length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let classList = [];

const enrollStudent = (firstName, lastName, age, currentMark) => {
      newStudent = {firstName, lastName, age, currentMark};
      classList.push(newStudent);
      console.log(classList);
  };

  enrollStudent("Mark", "Smith", 24, 85);
  enrollStudent("Dane", "Joe", 21, 90);
  enrollStudent("Steven", "McKnight", 23, 54);

  const total = classList.reduce( (acc, student) => { 
            return acc + student.currentMark
}, 0)


const getClassAverage = total / classList.length // 76.33333333333333
```

Comment: What exactly is "acc" after the classList.reduce referring to?

Comment: acc ==> acumulator (the previous state)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce